# How to make sure that iptables is completely disable?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

I want to disable iptables completely. I followed the instruction like

```
/etc/init.d/iptables close
```

it said there `No such file or directory`

```
[root@dataapp02 tmp]# service iptables stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  iptables.service
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.
```

And I found another command `firewalld`

```
[root@dataapp02 tmp]# service firewalld stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  firewalld.service
```

So far I am not sure iptables are disabled or not?

How do I check whether iptables disabled or not.

On  my computer I can open

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
```

But on the on-premises computer with firewall, iptables and http proxy whitelist, it said the connection time out.

Comment: *close iptables* - what do you mean by close. You wish disable iptables completely or you wish to stop connections from your computer to outside world.

Comment: Sorry, what I am saying is disable iptables completely.

Comment: `iptables --list | grep policy` try also without grep  - take look if some rules are on and default policy. also take look [that](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-turn-off-firewall-in-linux/) there is video,  it may help you to get started. And [this](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) specially *2. Getting Started*

Comment: also [this ubuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149629/how-do-i-prevent-iptables-from-loading-on-boot)

Comment: Firewalld and iptables are just wrapper tools that let you manage the net filter framework, you just have to stop the services if you use firewalls "systemctl stop firewalld.service" and for iptables "systemctl stop iptables.service".

Comment: If that can reassure you, you demonstrated that `iptables` is not running on your system.  You may be wondering if you have another firewall active but there is no generic way of checking that.  To check if `firewalld` is running, run `firewall-cmd --state`.

Comment: I tried  `systemctl stop iptables.service`, and got
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.

Comment: run `iptables --list | grep policy`, and got
 
**Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)**

How shall I read this output? What does it mean?

Comment: @cdhit it means iptables are enabled, mean they may work. Because of your `iptables -L` results - it mean no filter rules applyed, so you may think that iptables do nothing at the moment, if you have connection. If you wish disable technical capabilitys for iptables to work, accepted answer in ubuntu question above is for you.

Comment: @MolbOrg Mine is Red Hat 7.2

Comment: @cdhit probably you mean centos, RH7.2 is old as hell, RH not the same as RH enterprise. Anyway, should work, if iptables is't buildin in kernel. `lsmod | grep ipt` if you see *iptable_mangle, iptable_nat, ipt_MASQUERADE* and such - it is iptable modules, by unloading them with `modprobe -r module_name` you will disable iptables completely. kernel rebuild without iptables, also helps.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that what you seem to want is impossible (or very difficult). I don't think there's any easy way to truly remove the firewall functionality from the operating system. The best you can do, I think, is configure the OS to allow all network traffic.

The simplest, most straight-forward way I know of to accept all network traffic is to use the `iptables-restore` and `ip6tables-restore` commands to clear out all of the firewall rules and reset the policies to `ACCEPT`. You can use a settings file such as the following:

```
# accept-all.iptables

# Clear all iptables rules
# Load using iptables-restore and ip6tables-restore

*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

This format is read by `iptables-restore` and written by `iptables-save`.

You could then clear the IP4 rules using `iptables-restore` as follows:

```
sudo iptables-restore accept-all.iptables
```

And you could clear the IP6 rules using `ip6tables-restore` as follows:

```
sudo ip6tables-restore accept-all.iptables
```

Or you could do both at once:

```
cat accept-all.iptables \
| tee >(ip6tables-restore) \
| iptables-restore
```

The way to make these settings persist would depend on your OS. On Debian, for example, there is an `iptables-persistent` package which was designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

iptables is a tool that allows you to control netfilter. You can't "disable" iptables but you can ensure that netfilter is not interfering with your network traffic.

Permit all traffic and flush all rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT # ensure that default policy is ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT        # flush all input rules
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
iptables -F OUTPUT

iptables -t nat -F PREROUTING # flush the NAT tables
iptables -t nat -F INPUT
iptables -t nat -F OUTPUT
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
```

It's up to you to replicate the same pattern on the IPv6 stack (using ip6tables) and work out how to make these changes permanent. It could be `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` (for v4) but not guaranteed.

Answer (score -2):

```
/sbin/iptables -L
```

Will list all the active rules.

Comment: Actually it won't. It will list all the rules in the (default) `filter` table. There are also the `nat` and `mangle` and `security` tables.

Comment: This is the result of `iptables -L`.  @symcbean

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`